# Boolean datatype in SQL causing issues?

Tags: sql, database, create-table

If I wanted to use a datatype that acts like a boolean/binary/gives me Y/N, what datatype would I use?

I basically need YesNo to store any kind of boolean/binary/Y/N value.

This is what I have so far, however, isn't working.

```
CREATE TABLE TEST(
    TestID int(3) PRIMARY KEY,
    YesNo boolean
);

INSERT INTO TEST(TestID, YesNo) VALUES ('999', TRUE);
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  However, I think the error message is pretty clear.

Comment: @GordonLinoff How do I alter the code to not get the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think databases have a Boolean type. An alternative to this would be using a `BIT` instead. Then set this `BIT` value to either a 1 or 0. Also, It is standard practice for 0 to be construed as FALSE, 1 to be construed as TRUE and Nulls, when allowed, would be reflected as NULL.

Comment: Thanks for this, very much appreciated

Comment: Not all database have `BIT` types, either (SQL Server is the one I know about).

Comment: [PostgreSQL has a boolean type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/datatype-boolean.html)